# How to improve the time consuming of log and exponentiation operation

Tags: matlab, vector, digit

The theoretical result is a mixture of gamma ratios, like:sum(
A<sub>i</sub>Gamma(B<sub>i</sub>)/Gamma(C<sub>i</sub>)), in which `A` is a binomial coeff, and would be very hard to calculate by using `nchoosek` directly in matlab. So my solution is to decompose all elements in the results to `prod(vector)`, however, as the vector getting longer, I meet digit problem. So I changed the solution to get `x(1:n) = log(vector)` and then `rst = sum(exp(x))`. In practice, I found this is quite time consuming, especially when the # of gamma terms is very large.

Here is a code section:

```
    gamma_sum = zeros(1,x2+1);
    coef = ones(1,x2+1);
%     sub_gamma_sum = zeros(1,x2+1);
    %     coef(1) = prod(1./sqrt(1:x2));
    coef(1) = sum(log(1:x2))/2-sum(log([1:1-1 1:x2-1+1]));
    if x1>0
        %         gamma_sum(1) = gamma(beta)/gamma(alpha+beta)/...
        %             prod((alpha+beta:alpha+beta+x1-1));
        %         gamma_sum(1) = prod(1./(alpha+beta:alpha+beta+x1-1));
        gamma_sum(1) = sum(log(1./(alpha+beta:alpha+beta+x1-1)));
    else
        %         gamma_sum(1) = gamma(beta)/gamma(alpha+beta);
        %         gamma_sum(1) = 1;
        gamma_sum(1) = log(1);
    end
    for i = 2:x2+1
        %         coef(i) = prod((1:x2)./[1:i-1 1:x2-i+1]);
        %         coef(i) = exp(sum(log(1:x2))/2-sum(log([1:i-1 1:x2-i+1])));
        coef(i) = sum(log(1:x2))/2-sum(log([1:i-1 1:x2-i+1]));
        %         coef(i) = prod(1./[1:i-1 1:x2-i+1])*exp(sum(log(1:x2))/2);
        %         gamma_sum(i) = prod((beta:beta+i-2)./(alpha+beta:alpha+beta+i-2))*prod(1./(alpha+beta+i-1:alpha+beta+x1+i-2));%% den has x1+i-1 terms
        gamma_sum(i) = sum(log((beta:beta+i-2)./(alpha+beta:alpha+beta+i-2)))+sum(log(1./(alpha+beta+i-1:alpha+beta+x1+i-2)));
    end
```

In the code, coef is the A<sub>i</sub>, and gamma_sum is the rest part. Just found that when `x2`, i.e. the number of the terms of the gamma terms, the computing time is really troublesome. P.S: I tried to replace all `for` loop with matrix operation, but when `x2` increases the matrix size also makes the computing time consuming. Is there any way to solve the problem, like use some other method to solve the digit problem(number exceeds 1e300 or number less than e-200) more efficiently, i.e. guarantee the precision and increase the speed.

Answer (score 0):

This might make your system slower, but you can try `vpa()` for your big numbers, if you need a high precision and if you have a Symbolic Math toolbox. Here is the example:

```
>> exp(1000)
ans =    
   Inf    
>> vpa('exp(1000)',1000)     
ans =     
197007111401704699388887935224332312531693798532384578995280299138506385078244119347497807656302688993096381798752022693598298173054461289923262783660152825232320535169584566756192271567602788071422466826314006855168508653497941660316045367817938092905299728580132869945856470286534375900456564355589156220422320260518826112288638358372248724725214506150418881937494100871264232248436315760560377439930623959705844189509050047074217568.2267578083308102070668818911968536445918206584929433885943734416066833995904928281627706135987730904979566512246702227965470280600169740154332169201122794194769119334980240147712089576923975942544366215939426101781299421858554271852298015286303411058042095685866168239536053428580900735188184273075136717125183129388223688310255949141146674987544438726686065824907707203395789112200325628195551034220107289821072957315749621922062772097208051047568893649549635990627082681006282905378167473398226026683503867394140748723651685213836918959449223430784235236845739442
```

In this way you would be able to use enormous numbers in your calculations at the expense of increased memory usage and lower speed.

Comment: in fact I am in trouble with speed. What I am asking is how to make it faster. Sorry for the unclear description of my needs.